# FluentValidation Call RuleSet and Common Rules

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following class

```
public class ValidProjectHeader : AbstractValidator<Projects.ProjectHeader>
    {
        public ValidProjectHeader()
        {

            RuleFor(x => x.LobId).Must(ValidateLOBIDExists);
            RuleFor(x => x.CreatedByUserId).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.ProjectManagerId).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.ProjectName).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.SalesRepId).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.DeliveryDate).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.ProjectStatusId).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.DeptartmentId).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor(x => x.CustomerId).NotEmpty();

            RuleSet("Insert", () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.ProjectLines).Must(ValidateProjectLines).SetCollectionValidator(new ValidProjectLine());
            });
            RuleSet("Update", () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.ProjectLines).SetCollectionValidator(new ValidProjectLine());
            });


        }
```

and what i am trying to do is call the validation with the rulset but i also want to return the "common" rules when i call the validation with the RuleSet.

the Code I have for calling the validation is as follows

```
public abstract class BaseValidator
    {
        private List<ValidationFailure> _errors;
        public bool IsValid { get; protected set; }
        public List<ValidationFailure> Errors
        {
            get { return _errors; }
            protected set { _errors = value; }
        }
        public virtual bool CallValidation()
        {
            Errors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
            ValidatorAttribute val = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidatorAttribute), true)[0] as ValidatorAttribute;
            IValidator validator = Activator.CreateInstance(val.ValidatorType) as IValidator;
            FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(this);
            IsValid = result.IsValid;
            Errors = result.Errors.ToList();
            return result.IsValid;
        }

        public virtual bool CallValidation(string ruleSet)
        {
            Errors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
            ValidatorAttribute val = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidatorAttribute), true)[0] as ValidatorAttribute;
            IValidator validator = Activator.CreateInstance(val.ValidatorType) as IValidator;
            FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new FluentValidation.ValidationContext(this, new PropertyChain(), new RulesetValidatorSelector(ruleSet)));
            IsValid = result.IsValid;
            Errors = result.Errors.ToList();
            return result.IsValid;
        }

        public BaseValidator()
        {
            Errors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
        }
    }
```

I can call the Method `CallValidation` with the member `ruleSet` but it is not calling the "common" rules also.

I know I can create a "Common" RuleSet for running these rules but in that case i would have to call the validation with the Common RuleSet always.

Is there any way I can call the RuleSet and also call the common rules.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead you could do this:

```
using FluentValidation;
...
FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult resultCommon =
    validator.Validate(parameter, ruleSet: "default, Insert");
```

The `using` directive is required to bring the `Validate()` extension method from `DefaultValidatorExtensions` into scope, which has the `ruleSet` property. Otherwise you will only have the `Validate()` method available from inheriting `AbstractValidator<T>`, which doesn't have a `ruleSet` argument.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to have existed in the git source code since at least 2009, which is what led me here since the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: Great advice! In FluentValidation 6.2.1 the RuleSet argument case is different: "ruleSet:" instead of "Ruleset:". Example: validator.Validate(obj, ruleSet: "default, Insert");

Comment: The info about the using is so important, so many thanks for this, I couldn't figure out how to make this work before.

Answer (score 14):

In your Validator class create a method, that includes all "common" rules that need to be applied at all times.  Now you can call this method

- from your "create" RuleSet
- from outside of the RuleSet

Example

```
public class MyEntityValidator : AbstractValidator<MyEntity>
{
    public MyEntityValidator()
    {
        RuleSet("Create", () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress();
                ExecuteCommonRules();
            });

        ExecuteCommonRules();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rules that should be applied at all times
    /// </summary>
    private void ExecuteCommonRules()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.City).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

You define the RuleSet for an action in your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "Create")]  MyEntity model)
```

This will insure that requests to action Create will be validated with the RuleSet Create.  All other action will use the call to ExecuteCommonRules in controller.

Answer (score 4):

I have found one way to do it by adding a second `validator.Validate`
to the `CallValidation(string ruleSet)` method it is as follows

```
public virtual bool CallValidation(string ruleSet)
        {
            Errors = new List<ValidationFailure>();
            ValidatorAttribute val = this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidatorAttribute), true)[0] as ValidatorAttribute;
            IValidator validator = Activator.CreateInstance(val.ValidatorType) as IValidator;
            FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(new FluentValidation.ValidationContext(this, new PropertyChain(), new RulesetValidatorSelector(ruleSet)));
            FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult resultCommon = validator.Validate(this);
            IsValid = (result.IsValid && resultCommon.IsValid);
            Errors = result.Errors.Union(resultCommon.Errors).ToList();
            return IsValid;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried below and it works

```
   [CustomizeValidator(RuleSet = "default, Create")
```

Comment: This question (while very old) was to not work with the Attribute validation, but to call the AbstractValidator<T>.Validate Method. While this works I was looking for a way to do this in code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Fluent validation 10+ onwards.
      using FluentValidation;
     var validationResult = await 
     validator.ValidateAsync(account,options=>options("nameOfRuleSet"));
```

Comment: OP could use some explanations for your answer.