# FluentValidation - conditionally selecting a validator

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation (C#) to achieve validation of a complex object. My problem is that I'd like to select different validators for the the complete object given a specific properties of the object.

Assume the following structure:

```
public class MyComplexClass
{
    public string OneProperty;
    public string OtherProperty;
    public bool SelectionCriteria
}
```

On this object I'd like to use Validator1 if SelectionCriteria is true and Validator2 if SelectionCriteria is false. 
It is clear that validators can be nested for specific properties, but here I'd like to select a validator for the *complete* class. Something like this was in my mind:

```
public MyComplexClassValidator : AbstractValidator_MyComplexClass_
{
    public MyComplexClassValidator()
    {
    AddRule(new ConditionValidationAssignmentRule(new MyComplexClassValidator1,x=>x.SelectionCriteria))
    AddRule(new ConditionValidationAssignmentRule(new MyComplexClassValidator1,x=>!x.SelectionCriteria))

    } 
}

class ConditionalValidatorAssignmentRule : IValidationRule
{
    public string RuleSet
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IPropertyValidator> Validators
    {
        get
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }

    private IValidator _AssignedValidator;
    private bool _ExecuteValidation = false;
    private Func<string, bool> _Condition;

    public ConditionalValidatorAssignmentRule(IValidator validator, Func<string,bool> condition)
    {
        _AssignedValidator = validator;
        _Condition = condition;
    }

    public void ApplyCondition(Func<object, bool> predicate, ApplyConditionTo applyConditionTo = ApplyConditionTo.AllValidators)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationFailure> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {

        var ret = new List<FluentValidation.Results.ValidationFailure>();
        ret.AddRange(_AssignedValidator.Validate(context).Errors);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't manage to invoke the function with SelectionCriteria. 
Could you please advise how this should/could be done with the proper way? Again, I could do this all with the property validators and When-s, but I would like to assign separate validators based on one individual property to take care of the rest. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not realize this exactly, I managed to figure out a similar solution following the steps at [FluentValidation Call RuleSet and Common Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877227/fluentvalidation-call-ruleset-and-common-rules) which does the job.

This solution suggests the usage of RuleSets and validating based on them. There are a few points about it that I don't like:

- The 'common' and the 'specific' validation outcomes have to be merged (this is probably not the way FluentValidation was designed to be used)
- The validation rules are not entirely separated (all the rules are in the same validator, the only thing splitting them in parts is that they are grouped according to rulesets)
- The selection criteria is to be handled separately (I implemented a specific Validate function, in which the common and specific rules are executed, plus there the selection criteria is analyzed manually), while ideally it could be done as part of the validation in the design outlined in the original question.

So while this solution is workable, I'd still be very curious to get input on the original question to see if the proposed design could be realized in FluentValidation.